# Is there a function in BeanShell JMeter for get a value of a element in a decode token?

Tags: jmeter, base64, token, decode, beanshell

I have a decoded token in JMeter BeanShell, which contains

- Username,
- ContactGUID,
- among other

I need to get the value from ContactGUID

```
vars.put("deToken", new String(Base64.decodeBase64(vars.get("token"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a [GUID](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier)-like structure in the token you can get it using [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

First of all forget about Beanshell, since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31/) it's [recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting.

Groovy in its turn provides [find operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_find_operator) so you will be able to extract GUID from text like:

```
def contactGUID =  ((deToken =~ "([a-f0-9]{8}(-[a-f0-9]{4}){4}[a-f0-9]{8})")[0][1])
```

Demo:

[image]